# File input looking strange in safari but looking fine in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I am pretty new to web development. I have a file input box which just wont behave on Safari.

[image: What it looks like on Chrome -> GOOD]

[image: What it looks like on Safari -> BAD]

The upper one is how it is supposed to look and how it looks on chrome. The one below is on safari... Not so good..

Does anyone have any idea as to what might be costing this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide your HTML and CSS for us to be able to help.

Comment: Does Safari really display different texts? Odd.